# Create a space delimited text file from function results in Python 3.6

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a text file with a specific number of spaces in each column and populate the data from a function result in postgresql. The following is the code:

```
    with psycopg2.connect(connection stuff) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.callproc('makercr_nir')
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    head = ['My', 'head']
    nm = fname + '.txt'

    with open(nm, 'w') as fp:  
        file = csv.writer(fp, delimitor=' ')
        file.writerow(head)  # writes header row.
        file.writerows(rows)  # uses the writerows function on the list rows to output the data to the csv
```

My problem is that the results of the query look like this:

> (1953,00064_80,0,0,0,62.18,301.25,390.90,1019.10,876.57,593.50,2.41,0,0,3245.91)

but need to be output in the txt file like this, with that exact number of spaces for each column (the number of spaces do vary):

> `1953 00064_80        0.00    0.00    0.00   62.18  301.25  390.90 1019.10  876.57  593.50    2.41    0.00    0.00   3245.92`

There are about 13,100 rows returned in the function. What would be the best method to accomplish the desired output format?

Comment: You would need to say what the specific number of spaces for each column needs to be.

Comment: The First Column = 4 spaces filled by the year, a blank space, second column = 12 spaces filled by a varying number of characters, columns three through 15 for each monthly value are 8 spaces, and the last total column is 10 spaces. @MartinEvans

Comment: Maybe something like:

    s = '{0: <4} {1: <12}{2: <8}{3: <8}{4: <8}{5: <8}{6: <8}{7: <8}{8: <8}{9: <8}{10: <8}{11: <8}{12: <8}{13: <8}{14: <10}'

    for row in rows:
        s.format(*row)

This will yield:  '1952 00064_00    0       0       0       62.18   301.25  390.9   1019.1  876.57  593.5   2.41    0       0       3245.91   '

If you want the fields to be right-aligned, use >.

Comment: That isn't working, I'm not certain why? Do I need [0] around the position numbers? Or does s.format(*row) need to be put into a string variable and then written out?

Comment: Please edit your Question to explain _**That isn't working**_ with the code you have tried. What did you mean with: _**Do I need [0] around the position numbers?**_.